# Как дать права exe для чтения и изменения файлов в Program File | Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, inno-setup

у меня проблема.
Я создал exe файл с помощью pyinstaller и проверил - в своей директории он работает замечательно

Но после того как я создал установщик с помощью Inno Setup и установил exe в Program File то в консоль выводит ошибку `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C://Program Files (x86)/dir/data/user.txt'`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать: Можно как-то выдать права на чтения файлов exe-шнику или я смогу читать их только при запуске через администратора?
заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ!
В коде inno setup в самом конце добавляем строчки:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}"; Permissions: evryone-full
```

И всё)